# MYSQL multi table export to flat csv

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to export data from a Joomla recipe plugin that is no longer maintained and having trouble with the more complex sections.

I've been trying to study this article, which details a process which is similar to what I'm trying to achieve: http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2012/05/flattening-many-to-many-fields-for-mysql-to-csv-export/

Here's are the tables I'm working with:

**jos_rr_recipes**

```
    +-----------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
    | recipe_id | chef | title       | introtext       | portionstype  | portions   |
    +-----------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
    | 3         | 1    | Recipe ID 3 | Intro text ID 3 | 2             | 7-8 People |
    | 6         | 1    | Recipe ID 6 | Intro text ID 6 | 2             | 3-4 People |
    | 4         | 3    | Recipe ID 4 | Intro text ID 4 | 1             | 1 box      |
    | 5         | 3    | Recipe ID 5 | Intro text ID 5 | 1             | 10 wraps   |
    +-----------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+------------+
```

**jos_rr_categories**

```
    +-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
    | category_id | pretty_url |   title   | parent_id |
    +-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
    |           3 | 3-url      | 3 Title   |         0 |
    |         198 | 198-url    | 198 Title |         0 |
    |           2 | 2-url      | 2 Title   |         0 |
    |           5 | 5-url      | 5 Title   |         0 |
    |           1 | 1-url      | 1 Title   |         0 |
    |         169 | 169-url    | 169 Title |         0 |
    |         171 | 171-url    | 171 Title |         0 |
    |         149 | 149-url    | 149 Title |         3 |
    |         150 | 150--url   | 150 Title |         3 |
    |         151 | 151-url    | 151 Title |         3 |
    |         198 | 98-url     | 98 Title  |         3 |
    |         201 | 201-url    | 201 Title |       198 |
    |          21 | 21--url    | 21 Title  |       198 |
    |         100 | 100-url    | 100 Title |       198 |
    |           4 | 4-url      | 4 Title   |       169 |
    |          80 | 80-url     | 80 Title  |       169 |
    |          26 | 26-url     | 26 Title  |         2 |
    |         213 | 213-url    | 213 Title |       198 |
    |         303 | 303-url    | 303 Title |       171 |
    |          11 | 11-url     | 11 Title  |         2 |
    |         112 | 112-url    | 112 Title |         2 |
    |         231 | 231-url    | 231 Title |         1 |
    |         200 | 200-url    | 200 Title |         1 |
    |         181 | 181-url    | 181 Title |         1 |
    |          54 | 54-url     | 54 Title  |         3 |
    |         195 | 195-url    | 195 Title |       198 |
    |          10 | 10-url     | 10 Title  |       198 |
    |         226 | 226-url    | 226 Title |       150 |
    |         300 | 300-url    | 300 Title |       150 |
    +-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**jos_rr_recipecategory**

```
    +-----------+-------------+
    | recipe_id | category_id |
    +-----------+-------------+
    |         3 |         195 |
    |         3 |          10 |
    |         3 |         149 |
    |         3 |         201 |
    |         3 |          26 |
    |         3 |         231 |
    |         3 |          80 |
    |         3 |         303 |
    |         4 |          54 |
    |         4 |         300 |
    |         4 |           4 |
    |         4 |          21 |
    |         4 |          98 |
    |         4 |          26 |
    |         4 |         213 |
    |         5 |          26 |
    |         5 |          11 |
    |         5 |         112 |
    |         5 |         200 |
    |         6 |         201 |
    |         6 |           4 |
    |         6 |          26 |
    |         6 |         112 |
    |         6 |         231 |
    |         6 |         300 |
    +-----------+-------------+
```

**jos_sobi2_fields_data**

```
    +----+---------+--------------------+--------+
    | id | fieldid | data_txt           | itemid |
    +----+---------+--------------------+--------+
    | 4  | 7       | chef1@email.com    | 1      |
    | 5  | 13      | Description Chef 1 | 1      |
    | 28 | 7       | chef3@email.com    | 3      |
    | 32 | 13      | description chef 3 | 3      |
    +----+---------+--------------------+--------+
```

Some of the categories are multiple layers deep, however there is no way to input this into WordPress that I'm aware of, so I'm happy to have them just put into separate columns as group_concat, under each primary header, in the output.

There parents that I will import into their own separate taxonomies in WordPress:

```
    Course/Dish     = 105
    Meals           = 199
    Main Ingredient = 2
    Difficulty      = 5
    Cuisine         = 1
    Equipment       = 169
    Rainbow         = 171
```

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
SELECT
recipes.recipe_id AS ID,
recipes.title AS Title,
chef.data_txt AS Chef,
recipes.introtext AS Description,
IFNULL(IF (recipes.portionstype = 1 , recipes.portions,''),'') AS Yield,
IFNULL(IF (recipes.portionstype = 2 , recipes.portions,''),'') AS Servings
FROM 
jos_rr_recipes AS recipes
JOIN jos_sobi2_fields_data AS chef
ON recipes.chef = chef.itemid AND chef.fieldid = 7
GROUP BY recipes.recipe_id
```

Now I have no idea how to pull each taxonomy into their own column. I have tried the following without success:

```
SELECT
recipes.recipe_id AS ID,
recipes.title AS Title,
chef.data_txt AS Chef,
recipes.introtext AS Description,
IFNULL(IF (recipes.portionstype = 1 , recipes.portions,''),'') AS Yield,
IFNULL(IF (recipes.portionstype = 2 , recipes.portions,''),'') AS Servings,
IFNULL(tax_ingr.ingredients,'') AS "Taxonomy Ingredients"
FROM (
    SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(cat.title SEPARATOR '|') AS ingredients
    FROM jos_rr_recipecategory AS catlink
    LEFT JOIN jos_rr_categories AS cat
    ON catlink.category_id = cat.category_id AND cat.parent_id = 2
    GROUP BY recipe_id
) AS tax_ingr,
jos_rr_recipes AS recipes
JOIN jos_sobi2_fields_data AS chef
    ON recipes.chef = chef.itemid AND chef.fieldid = 7
GROUP BY recipes.recipe_id
```

This just takes a long time to query and doesn't provide the expected results.

After 3 days, I just can't get my head around this. :(

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got my head around this and came up with a solution. Once I understood the concepts of using subqueries it was actually fairly straight forward.

**The light bulb that went off in my head was:**

Each Subquery essentially becomes it's own temporary table to be used in the query, referred to by it's alias. In other words, we are creating the links between the tables in each subquery and then using their outputted data in the SELECT statement as if it were a normal table.

If anyone is interested in the final query it's below, albiet with slightly different naming due to using a different dataset.

```
SELECT
recipe.recipe_id AS ID, 
recipe.title AS Title,
LOWER(IFNULL(recipe.chef,'nochef@aaronportbury.com'))    AS Chef,
recipe.description AS Description, 
recipe.yield,
recipe.servings, 
IFNULL(ingr_link.val,'') AS 'Ingredients',
IFNULL(course_link.val,'') AS 'Course', 
IFNULL(meal_link.val,'') AS 'Meal',
IFNULL(dif_link.val,'') AS 'Difficulty', 
IFNULL(cuis_link.val,'') AS 'Cuisine',
IFNULL(equi_link.val,'') AS 'Equipment',
FROM (
        SELECT 
        r.recipe_id, 
        r.title,
        c.data_txt AS chef,
        r.introtext AS description,
        IFNULL(IF (r.portionstype = 1 , r.portions,''),'') AS yield, # Checks to see type from Portionstype. If 1, then it's a Yield. Else leave empty
        IFNULL(IF (r.portionstype = 2 , r.portions,''),'') AS servings, # Checks to see type from Portionstype. If 2, then it's a Serving. Else leave empty
        FROM jos_rr_recipes AS r
        LEFT JOIN jos_sobi2_fields_data AS c
            ON r.chef = c.itemid AND c.fieldid = 7
) AS recipe
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
        rc.recipe_id AS rid,
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(cat.title SEPARATOR ';;'),'') AS val # Uses Group_Concat function to combine all Ingredients related to the recipe ID and seperates them with ;;
        FROM jos_rr_recipecategory AS rc
        LEFT JOIN jos_rr_categories AS cat
            ON rc.category_id = cat.category_id AND cat.parent_id = 2
        GROUP BY rc.recipe_id
) AS ingr_link
ON recipe.recipe_id = ingr_link.rid
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        rc.recipe_id AS rid,
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(cat.title SEPARATOR ';;'),'') AS val
        FROM jos_rr_recipecategory AS rc
        LEFT JOIN jos_rr_categories AS cat          
            ON rc.category_id = cat.category_id 
                AND (cat.parent_id = 3 
                    OR cat.parent_id = 23 
                    OR cat.parent_id = 26 
                    OR cat.parent_id = 28 
                    OR cat.parent_id = 29 
                    OR cat.parent_id = 30 
                    OR cat.parent_id = 59 
                    OR cat.parent_id = 211)  # Here I just found all the parent ids and created multiple OR tests to collate them.
        GROUP BY rc.recipe_id
) AS course_link
ON recipe.recipe_id = course_link.rid
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        rc.recipe_id AS rid,
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(cat.title SEPARATOR ';;'),'') AS val
        FROM jos_rr_recipecategory AS rc
        LEFT JOIN jos_rr_categories AS cat
            ON rc.category_id = cat.category_id AND cat.parent_id = 198
        GROUP BY rc.recipe_id
) AS meal_link
ON recipe.recipe_id = meal_link.rid
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        rc.recipe_id AS rid,
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(cat.title SEPARATOR ';;'),'') AS val
        FROM jos_rr_recipecategory AS rc
        LEFT JOIN jos_rr_categories AS cat
            ON rc.category_id = cat.category_id AND cat.parent_id = 5
        GROUP BY rc.recipe_id
) AS dif_link
ON recipe.recipe_id = dif_link.rid
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        rc.recipe_id AS rid,
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(cat.title SEPARATOR ';;'),'') AS val
        FROM jos_rr_recipecategory AS rc
        LEFT JOIN jos_rr_categories AS cat
            ON rc.category_id = cat.category_id AND cat.parent_id = 1
        GROUP BY rc.recipe_id
) AS cuis_link
ON recipe.recipe_id = cuis_link.rid
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
        rc.recipe_id AS rid,
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(cat.title SEPARATOR ';;'),'') AS val
        FROM jos_rr_recipecategory AS rc
        LEFT JOIN jos_rr_categories AS cat
            ON rc.category_id = cat.category_id AND cat.parent_id = 169
        GROUP BY rc.recipe_id
) AS equi_link
ON recipe.recipe_id = equi_link.rid
GROUP BY recipe.recipe_id
```

I simply used multiple joined subqueries to filter the content down to what I needed and then repeated for each category I wanted.

Hope this helps others.